# Pass parameters between routes in nativesscript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In a NativeScript app I have two routes as bellow :

```
{ path : "boxes" , component : BoxesPage } ,
{ path : "card" , component : CardPage } ,
```

In the BoxesPage I'm trying to pass something to CardPage like this :

```
constructor ( private _routerExtention : RouterExtensions , private _router : Router) {
    }

onItemTap ( _box ) {
        let navigationExtras : NavigationExtras = {
            queryParams : { 'box' : _box } ,
            fragment    : 'anchor'
        };
        this._router.navigate( [ '/card' ] , navigationExtras );
    }
```

Then in the CardPage component :

```
 ngOnInit () : any {
        this.route.params.subscribe( ( _box : Box ) => {

                console.log( _box );   //undefined or {}

        } );
        return undefined;
    }
```

Question is :

Is this the right way ?

How should I get my box object inside the CardPage ?

Worth mentioning that I'm using Angular2 withing the NativScript.

I've tried everything but the documentation is extremely poor unfortunately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using route params as described in angular2's docs?

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#configuration

Note: { path : "boxes/:boxId" , component : BoxesPage } ,

Answer (score 6):

if you want to pass complex data(Object) between one component to other component stringify the object and pass it to other component to parse JSON by using object.

**app.component.ts:**

```
public appListComponent(item: any) {

    const getData: string = item;

    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams: {
            DataList: JSON.stringify(getData)
        }   
    };
    this.routerExtensions.navigate(["app-modal"], navigationExtras);
}
```

**app.modal.component.ts:**

```
 public constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {    

      this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {

        this.getParamData = params["DataList"];

        let obj: ModalData = JSON.parse(this.getParamData);
        console.log("Name", obj.name);
        console.log("Description", obj.description);

    });

    }
```

**modaldata.ts:**

```
export class ModalData {
  name: string;
  description: string;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my answer in this similar post: [NativeScript + Angular Navigation context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943048/nativescript-angular-navigation-context/38983109#38983109) . Basically you do this via "route arguments" which are strings. Unfortunately you cannot pass "entire" JS/TS objects but you can implements a service which can retrieve those via the provided string arguments. For roe details and code snippets check my response in the other thread.

Here is a short intro if the other thread:

> Passing objects while navigating in Angular + NativeScript is not the same as vanila NativeScript. The routing is entirely implemented via angular specifications which means you will need to use their implementation. The current RC5 version of Angular 2 uses the following navigation (routing).